# Mongoid Alize - alize does not work with default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have models structure such as:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Alize

  field :name
  field :visible, type: Mongoid::Boolean

  default_scope -> { where(visible: true) }

  has_many :posts 
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Alize

  field :visible, type: Mongoid::Boolean

  default_scope -> { where(visible: true, 'user_fields.visible' => true) }

  belongs_to :user

  alize :user, :visible
end
```

When I set in Post and User visible: true it works, but denormalization doesn't work when in I set visible: false in Post instance. 
How can I tell alize to work through 'unscoped'?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.